# How to create hierarchy of projects in MS Project Server PWA?

Tags: hierarchy, ms-project-server-2010

I need to create a hierarchy of projects as well as projects access rights within MS-PWA.

the idea is to have a "Corporate Project" , of which underneath it resides our R&D, Finance, Marketing projects.

- Restricitions off course should apply per project (some will have access to the root project - while others only access to their specific projects (sales people, marketing dept, etc.)

Is it possible to create such Hierarchy in MS-Project Server 2010 PWA?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is: No, you cannot insert project into another project using PWA, you cannot define cross project links using PWA. This can be done only using Project Pro.

And btw we also started with the same idea: to have a master project and manage security on a level of sub projects. That idea failed because it took too long to open the master - Project Pro opens all subproject together with master to update progress; another problem was high integration of the subprojects - too many cross project links.

One of reasons why you may want to create such structure is to see a progress of the whole company using data from departmental subprojects. Here is another problem - only Project Pro can update status of the master.

I would recommend to create a view(s) in PWA just to see all of the projects grouped somehow together - this will be easier and faster.